# Is it better to choose Nvidia's proprietary drivers(319) by ubuntu repo over Bumblebee?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS on my dell xPS L502X laptop. I freshly installed ubuntu on my system yesterday. I want to know that is it safe & better now if i choose Nvidia drivers over bumblebee, bcz i think they are going to support linux now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, stick to bumblebee

Nvidia are *starting* to release support for optimus graphics cards but this is still really really limited compared to what bumblebee can do for you. You will be still installing Nvidia drivers with bumblebee - but it will be managed by bumblebee itself.

Its not hard to install bumblebee on Ubuntu, there are some instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) if you would like to take a look at them.